# Alamofire Unable to infer closure type in the current context

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm creating the extension for DataRequest to log events

```
func log() -> Self {
        let responseSerializer = DataRequest.jsonResponseSerializer(options: .allowFragments)
        return response(queue: nil, responseSerializer: responseSerializer) { response in
            if let object = response.result.value {
                /* do the job */
            }
        }
}
```

and got the error `Unable to infer closure type in the current context`
Since it has `(DataResponse<T.SerializedObject>) -> Void` generic type, is there a way to explicitly set the type to fix this error?

**Alamofire version:**
4.7.2
**Xcode version:**
9.3 
**Swift version:**
4.0
**Platform(s) running Alamofire:**
iOS

Comment: Running same versions but I don't get that error. Share more details maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func log() -> Self {
        let responseSerializer = DataRequest.jsonResponseSerializer()
        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer) { [weak self] response in
            guard let _self = self else { return }
            _self.printRequestString(response)
        }
    }
```

Works well.